# How to Select K2 Category to Show When Creating Menu Item

Tags: k2, menu

Can anyone tell me how you select WHICH K2 category to show when assigning it to a new menu item?  It gives you the option to show a list of items under a specific category, but no way to pick which category.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple indeed:
Once you choose Menu Item Type as `K2 | Categories`
you click `Options` tab and in `Select Categories` field choose the category you want, and adjust other settings per your liking.

[image]

Comment: well don't I feel stupid.  Thanks Mikan for your help!